# What is the fastest and most secure messenger on Windows Phone?

Tags: 8.1, lumia-520, messenger

Defining **Secure** for this question: A secure messenger is one that doesn't connect people based on their mobile number. Or, even if it does connect people based on their number, I get to choose who can connect with me. *Maybe secure is not the right word here, because I am not laying stress on data encryption. I want to remain hidden.*

Defining **Fast**: A fast messenger is one which doesn't take long to start and shouldn't require a strong net connection.

**Senario**

I want to connect to few close friends and don't want to be seen/connected to every person who has my number saved in their address book. Something like chatting with the old fashioned Gtalk and Yahoo messenger.

"*Then why not use Gtalk or Yahoo?*" I have tried Yahoo and Gtalk equivalent apps but they tend to be slow. I often have to go to rural areas where there is no 3G, only EDGE, and these apps rely on a strong internet connection. Among all the apps I have tried only WhatsApp seems to work properly on EDGE.

Apps that I have tried so far:

- WhatsApp: fast but not secure (everyone can ping me)
- Hike: slow
- IM+ (used with gmail): secure but very slow
- Skype: too slow, takes a long time to connect on EDGE and messages don't get delivered instantly
- Telegram: not secure
- Kik: the perfect app. Secure, as it allows me to connect via an ID, and fast, but the push notifications are not working properly. Crashes a lot!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK the best option would be Threema. This messaging tool is made by a swiss company supporting end-to-end encryption and no need for any personal data if you don't want. According to the company any data will be deleted from their servers as soon as a message was delivered. I haven't tried it myself yet but I heard some good things.

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/threema/c242c3e3-8d10-489a-9415-0ba215c85135